How to configure nginx proxy server to serve react app and a node.js back-end server?
I'm running my node.js back-end server at port 3001 while my react.js is running at port 3000 i have been trying to setup my nginx server to no avail, kept getting either bad gateway or cors error please help below is my nginx config file, refer below:
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/157.245.3.88/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html;

    server_name 157.245.3.88:3000;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:3000 http://$server_name/;

    }   
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name 157.245.3.88:3001;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:3001 http://$server_name/;

        }

        location /order-checkout {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/order-checkout;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:3001/order-checkout http://$server_name/;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/api;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:3001/api http://$server_name/;
        }

}


root directive takes directory where static files are located. I don't think /var/www/157.245.3.88/ is directory. Create a dir in /var/www/<name> and put your react bundle there. For this example i'll assume /var/www/example_com/ and i'll also assume domain name is example.com.
server_name takes domain name not ip address. So it should be example.com or/and www.example.com.
You don't need proxy_redirect. proxy_pass is more than enough.
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_tokens off;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65s;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen      [::]:80;
        server_name    www.example.com example.com;

        location / {
          root /var/www/example_com/; # <- directory where react bundle is stored.
        }

        location ~ /api {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001; # don't put `/api`, nginx will append path for you.
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ~ /order-checkout {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001; 
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

}

once completed test config by running
nginx -t

then restart nginx.
HeadsUp: I have kept config simple as possible to your question but you might endup adding more config. Like adding ssl certificate rules (certbot), redirecting www.example.com to example.com (or vice-versa), logging (access/error) and more. Refer docs for more.

I think instead of adding a react bundle in the /www you can simply use the pm2 to keep your react app running and simply setup reverse proxy for that localhost port.
let me know if you need a server bloc code for that
server{
server_name www.lux-ecards.com lux-ecards.com;
location / {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

}

above is the basic code bloc which you can use while running your react app using pm2 so above code bloc will get a request from the 3000 port and will redirect the request to my domain so for this you can use your IP address instead

yes i need server block code please
